# What can be the reason why i get an Nodejs Error EPERM: 3000?

Tags: node.js, web-deployment

I'm deploying my node.js ts application on ubuntu server

app.js file listening to port 3000

```
var port = 3000
app
    .use(authRoutes_1.default.routes())
    .use(keysRoutes_1.default.routes())
    .use(exchangesRoutes_1.default.routes())
    .use(wishlistRoutes_1.default.routes())
    .listen(port, function () {
      console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
    });
```

When i approach my domen through browser i get an error **listen eperm 3000**

Then i created another one simple server listener js file with the following code

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
  res.end('Hello World!');
});
server.listen(3000);
```

And suprisingly it works perfectly well

Another funny thing that running both files from ubuntu using node app.js throws the same EPERM error

How to solve this puzzle?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like port 3000 is already used by another process. Can you try something like `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` to check if there is any other process using that port ? Or can you try change to another port to see if your node server works ?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mention in code that second example using the same port and works well